# Edit Screen Capture QR Code

Tags: android, zxing

I'm trying to edit the screen activity capture QR code using ZXing Library, how to do this? What should edit to achieve something like this:

[image]

and avoid the screen on default.

Thanks for you prompt request.

Happy day for all!